# Azure File Sync Agent v15

Tags: azure, azure-storage

After Update to Version 15 of Azure FileSync Agent, I tried to find the new function
Invoke-StorageSyncServerChangeDetection

==========================================================================
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
Azure File Sync: List per item sync errors
Server Name: DK01DCGSFIL01
Script version 2.1
Installed Azure File Sync agent version: 15.0.0.0
```

==========================================================================

But is doesn't exist. It is described in the release: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-release-notes#agent-version-15000

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Azure File Sync: List per item sync errors`, cause and prevention of this error as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-troubleshoot?tabs=portal1%2Cazure-portal):

1. The last completed sync session did not have `per-item errors`. The portal should be updated soon to show 0 Files Not Syncing. By default, the  script will only show `per-item errors` for the last completed sync session. To view `per-item errors` for all sync sessions, use the
   `-ReportAllErrors` parameter.

To prevent the above cause, check the most recent Event ID 9102 in the Telemetry event log to confirm the `PerItemErrorCount` is 0.

2. The `ItemResults` event log on the server wrapped due to too many `per-item errors` and the event log no longer contains errors for this sync group.

To prevent the above cause, increase the `ItemResults` event log size.
The `ItemResults` event log can be found under `"Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\FileSync\Agent"` in Event Viewer.